# MVC4 Get Cookie Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my controller im setting a simple cookie value

```
var menuCookie = new HttpCookie("menuC");
            menuCookie.Value= account.MinimisedMenu.ToString();
            menuCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
            Response.Cookies.Add(menuCookie);
```

then on the page I need a bool value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  m =@Request.Cookies["menuC"].Value;

        if (m) {
            alert(m);
        };
});
```

But Im getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined"

This what the browser renders

```
  var m = false;
        m =False; //<--doe not like
```

is it because its uppercase?, what do I need to do to fix?

Comment: Try `@Response.Cookies["menuC"]`

Comment: Cookies are not intended to use like this. Instead use ViewBag to store data to access them in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is because it is in upper case, so JavaScript doesn't understand it. So you need to set it to lower case somewhere:

Option 1: on the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    m = @Request.Cookies["menuC"].Value.ToLower();
    if (m) {
        alert(m);
    };
});
```

Option 2: in the cookie, which is probably a better choice (write once, read many)

```
menuCookie.Value = account.MinimisedMenu.ToString().ToLower();
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact requirements, also remember that it can sometimes be easier to use razor to alter your JS so the client browser doesn't have to think as much (using cookies to communicate from controller to view is obviously inefficient). Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    @if (MyViewModel.ShowMenuC)
    {
        <text>
        alert("menu c jquery stuff here!");
        </text>
    }
});
```